# Error ITunesSoftwareService.framework missing

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm running into problems archiving an app using Xcode 4.2 iOS5 b6 under an EnterpiseDistributionProfile.

The Error is:
The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources

Could not find out anything about this, didn't use it on purpose. What is is? Is this a problem with the beta?

I can publish the app via iTunes by the way and it seems to work, just a little trouble with a pickerView after coming back from camera use. But I don't think it is related to this missing framework.